# Android WebView standard ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-webview

I'd like to have the context menu for the WebView content, like in the standard browser we have (see the images below).

Tried to explicitly enable the webView longClick, no luck.

So the question is - is there a way to enable the "standard" context menus in the web view ?
If there is, the way to customize it's appearance (meaning the style) would be also highly appreciated.

I'm familiar with the menus construction and it looks like the worst way to achieve the standard functionality when you have to rewrite it yourself.

[image: Android browser context menu]
[image: Android browser context menu]